# postgresql make existing primary key auto incrementing when inserting

Tags: postgresql

Existing table with 5 columns.

`qid` which is the PK, `question` `geo_type` `user_input` `active`

I need to be able to insert into the table with each new insert getting a new primary key id (which would be the max existing id +1).

So i need to be able to do this

```
insert into sip_questions (question,geo_type,user_input,active) values('noury','octagon',TRUE,TRUE)
```

but this give me this error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "s_questions_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (qid)=(1) already exists.

********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "s_questions_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (qid)=(1) already exists.
```

this is the table

```
CREATE TABLE public.sip_questions
(
  qid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('s_questions_qid_seq'::regclass),
  question character varying(200),
  geo_type character varying(10),
  user_input boolean,
  active boolean,
  CONSTRAINT s_questions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (qid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.sip_questions
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

i know how to do this from a fresh table like this

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

and every insert will increment the PK without me having to specify the id column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new sequence must be bumped to the current max value.

You  can reset it using

```sql
SELECT setval('s_questions_qid_seq', max(id)) FROM sip_questions;
```